# Need help with profile removal question

Tags: civievent

[image]

It's these two items at the bottom. It came from when I was trying to set up profiles. Can someone tell me how to get rid of them? "who do you vote for" and "individual"

Answer (score 1):

They are custom fields, You should see them under Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Custom Fields